# display select option from database when select option change

Tags: php

```
<tr>
  <td><label class="label label-success">Building Name: </label></td>
  <td>
    <select class="form-control" name="building_name" required>
      <option value="">Select Building</option>
      <?php
      include '../Database/db.php';
      $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM building");
      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
      ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $row['building_name']; ?>"><?php echo $row['building_name']; ?></option>

      <?php } ?>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><label class="label label-success">Floor: </label></td>
  <td>
    <select class="form-control" name="floor" required>
      <option value="">Select Floor</option>
      <option>></option>

    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
```

can anyone help me i want to display the floor of the selected building from the database. if i choose the building the floor will be display on select option floor.

Comment: where the floors info is stored? db structure will be helpful as well.

Comment: it is in the building database.

Comment: definitely they are there. table, structure, anything...

Comment: it is like when i choose country the province will be on a selected option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use AJAX to get the database value to display in DROPDOWN

```
$('#building_name').change(function(){
var building_name=  $('#building_name').val();
$.ajax({
url: "index.php", //Change it yours
type: "post",
data: {building_name: building_name}, 
success: function(data) {
    if(data != "false")
{
    $('#Floor').html(data); 
}
else{
alert("No value");}
}
});
});
```

And PHP FUNCTION should be

```
  $building_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['building_name']);
  $res2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM building  WHERE building_name = '{$building_name}'");
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res2)){
  echo '<option value="'.$row['floor_name'].'">'.$row['floor_name'].'</option>';
  }
```

Comment: Yes when you select  <select class="form-control" name="building_name"  id="building_name"required>. It will get floor drop-down accordingly 'building_name'

Comment: What you have done. Because I have given Sample Code for recruitment. Change it yours like table name, column name change it

Comment: this are my columns name, building_name, floor, location and the table name is building

Comment: the floor is on the table building

Comment: OK you want floor drop down display according to building drop down option? or you want display all floor in building table?

Comment: I have edit the php function in above function. Try it

Comment: i copy the codes but it didn't work. it think the problem is on ajax

Comment: Did use $(document).ready(function()
{  }); in start on javascript ?

Comment: nothing. i select of select option building but when i click floor there is no data appear.

Comment: press F12 after select  option building. There would display a error. Find it and tell me

Comment: Did you change the url in ajax as it yours?

Comment: did you add id in <select class="form-control" name="floor" id="floor" required>

Comment: $('#floor').html(data);  i think it is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing your database setup or structure here's is an example of how you could achieve this:

```
<?php require_once('../Database/db.php'); ?>
<tr>
  <td><label class="label label-success">Building Name: </label></td>
  <td>
    <select class="form-control" name="building_name" required">
      <option value="">Select Building</option>
      <?php
      $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM building");
      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
      ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $row['building_name']; ?>"><?php echo $row['building_name']; ?></option>
      <?php } ?>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><label class="label label-success">Floor: </label></td>
  <td>
    <select class="form-control" name="floor" required>
      <option value="">Select Floor</option>
      <?php
      $building_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['building_name']);
      $res2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM floor WHERE building_id = '{$building_name}'");
      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res2)){
      ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $row['floor_name']; ?>"><?php echo $row['floor_name']; ?></option>
      <?php } ?>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
```

You need to pass the posted parameter to an WHERE clause in the SQL. Note that you should be escaping malicious code form the posted parameters.

I'm also assuming that you have this html code inside a `form` tag along with a submit button

Comment: just curious with this approach - how you will execute second PHP part of code (floor related) without refreshing the page after selecting the buiding above?

Comment: @mitkosoft He is not asking how to achieve  this without refreshing the page.