# I am able to retrieve data from a database into a select option tag. So is there a way to display an option selected and display it in a text field?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

$row[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HegSV.png) is the course title in the db table, $row[2] or $stu_type is the study type(under or postgraduate).
Now, I am trying to make the selected value display in a text field. So since the values are being retrieved, that's fine.
So say i select course1 (undergraduate) from the option, the value of $stu_type needs to:

1. display in the textfield,
2. change whenever i change the option value

This is the form image

[image]

i have gone through this link [display select option from database when select option change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35648559/display-select-option-from-database-when-select-option-change) but this isn't what i want to do

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_courses";
$bam = mysqli_query($con, $sql);    
<select style="text-transform: uppercase;" name="title" id="title" class="form-control">
<?php while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($bam)):;?>                                        
<?php
$stu_type = '';
if ($row1[2] == 'undergraduate') {
$stu_type = 'UnderGraduate';
}
else if ($row1[2] == 'postgraduate') {
$stu_type = 'PostGraduate';
}
?>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('#title').change(function(){
$('#stu_type').val($(this).find(':selected').attr('data'));
});
});
</script>
<option value="<?php echo $row1[0]; ?>"><?php echo $row1[1]; ?> - <?php echo $stu_type;?></option>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</select>
<input type="text" name="stu_type" id="stu_type" value="<?=$_POST['title']?>">
```

Comment: use `echo "your text or <select> or something else"`

Comment: @xmastertje i have to submit that back to database. So it needs its value

Comment: If the select is part of the form, it will be sent to the php if you submit or ajax the form

Comment: @mplungjan could you link me to where it has been asked and answered? Cos i checked before posting this.

Comment: Reload your question and see the 3 links I gave

Comment: @mplungjan it is not changing nor displaying. It has to display before it can be sent

Comment: @mplungjan Okay i have seen those links.

Comment: Put this after the form or in the head and make sure jQuery is loaded: `$(function(){
$('#title').on("change",function(){
  $('#stu_type').val(this.value);
});
});`

Comment: If you want to get something from the server, you need to ajax it: `$(function(){ $('#title').on("change",function(){ $.post("someserveraction.php",{ "title":this.value},function(result) { $('#stu_type').val(result); }); }); });`